# How I send a mail written by Vietnamese in SpringMVC?

Tags: email, spring-mvc, utf-8, send

I want to send a mail with UTF-8, but it's not working

Here is the code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/sendEmail")
public class SendEmailController {

  @Autowired
  private JavaMailSender mailSender;

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String doSendEmail(HttpServletRequest request) {
      // takes input from e-mail form
      final String recipientAddress = request.getParameter("recipient");

      final String subject = request.getParameter("subject");

      final String message = request.getParameter("message");


      // prints debug info
      System.out.println("To: " + recipientAddress);
      System.out.println("Subject: " + subject);
      System.out.println("Message: " + message);


      mailSender.send(new MimeMessagePreparator() {

        @Override
        public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(
        mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
        messageHelper.setTo(recipientAddress);
        messageHelper.setSubject(subject);
        //messageHelper.setText(message);
        mimeMessage.setContent(message, "text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        }
      });



      // forwards to the view named "Result"
      return "Result";
  }

}
```

I use this bean with:

```
<bean id="mailSender"
    class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="host" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <property name="port" value="465" />
    <property name="username" value="khanghuynh92@gmail.com" />
    <property name="password" value="secret" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="javaMailProperties">
    <props>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.auth">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.class">
    javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.socketFactory.port">465</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">true</prop>
    <prop key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">true</prop>
    </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

As result I get following at google mail: TÃ´i lÃ  ngÆ°á» i Viá»‡t Nam

Can I convert to VietNamese?

Thanks in advance, Khang

Comment: You've exposed your gmail password!

Comment: I've removed the password from your post but you should change it if you haven't already

Comment: I suspect your data is "corrupt" before you even build the email message. You could prove this by writing the message out to a file using UTF-8 encoding.
Also, can you describe your J2EE server setup and what you're doing to post the data in?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said what the text is supposed to say but I assume the message is proper Vietnamese characters that have been posted using a web form in the `message` parameter.

The problem is likely that the web form is being posted using a local character-set rather than UTF-8.

Set the form to POST using UTF-8 with:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" ... >
```